# Do temporary variables stop an algorithm from being in-place?

Tags: c++, structure, in-place

I have written an algorithm for creating the consecutive maximum list of an original list A, such that `a(i+1)=max(a(i),a(i+1))`.

OUT OF PLACE ALG:

```
void conMax(int A[], int maxA[],int n)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (A[i]>=A[i-1])
        {
            maxA[i]=A[i];
        }
        else
        {
            maxA[i]=A[i-1];
        }
    }
}
```

IN PLACE ALG:

```
void inConMax(int a[],int n)
{
    int temp = -INFINITY;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(temp>a[i])
        {
            int k = temp;
            temp = a[i];
            a[i]=k;

        }
        else
        {
            temp=a[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Will using temporary variables within the loop to avoid using another array (maxA) stop my new alg from being in-place?

input: int a[9] = {7,5,9,23,24,6,4,19,20}

output: 7 7 9 23 24 24 6 19 20

Comment: No, it won’t. It’s often pretty impossible to avoid using any other storage than the data itself. It’s only about the actual data set not being copied to another place. But using -1 as index will cause undefined behavior here.

Comment: Regarding the `-1` index, maybe you should just skip the first element altogether for the result. It doesn't really make sense to get the maximum between a number and a non-existent number (*the left of 0th element*).

Comment: Changed a[-1] to the math.h library -INFINITY. And also I only added it because the example in the assignment question was the following: For example, given A = [7, 5, 9, 23] it returns [7, 7, 9, 23]. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you using raw C arrays?  Why not use `std::max_element`?

Comment: Um, `int` variables represent a **finite** range; there is no infinity. `INFINITY` is a **floating-point** infinite value; assigning `-INFINITY` to an `int` won't do anything useful. Use `INT_MIN` or `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`.

Comment: To add to @SamiKuhmonen In complexity theory, any in-place algorithm can use an arbitrary (!= infinite) amount of temporary storage so long as the amount does not depend on the input size.

Comment: Using *any index outside the allocated memory* is not ok. You can’t just go outside the bounds, not one, not infinity. If I have seven books and ask you to bring me the -7th, what will you bring?